# django make request user to api authenticated user

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a application in django. I have an authentication api from another application. I take input from user via form and post the input to the api in json. After I get success message from api and my user is authenticated to api I want to make that user as `request.user` in django.

Is there any way I can do it. I am thinking of doing it in middleware in `process_view`. Is this right approach ? But I have no idea how to do it.

Any suggestion will be appriciated.

Comment: Django gives a chance to implement custom authentication ways. Please have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends

Comment: I am not using oauth2.. I just want to call some url with post data and get response from them..

Comment: You should include your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really doing it thru Django views, you can manually login the user with:

```
# imports needed
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# hard way to login a user
user = User.objects.filter(username=INPUT_USERNAME).first()
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(request, user)
```

If you need to logout:

```
logout(request)
```